# double click to edit a QtreeWidget column

Tags: python, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget in which it has 4 columns (Name, version, ID, Location). While I have the first 3 columns populated, I had wanted the last column - Location to be user-input where Users have to specify the file location of another file before it gets run by another function.

Even so, I would like to ask if is it possible for this particular column to be double-clicked for such file path inputting?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374558/3366053) answer describes a solution for what you want without changing from the QTreeWidget convenience class.

Basically, for each item you place into that column, connect its itemDoubleClicked to a custom slot which runs item.editItem()

*For reference, the term you probably should have been searching for if you knew it was "edit triggers"

Comment: Hey thanks for the info but was wondering if it is any possible to change the solution you given in the link easily into python? Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it certainly is.
[http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html?highlight=edittriggers#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.setEditTriggers]  
[http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTreeWidgetItem.html?highlight=treewidget#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.setFlags]  
[http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Qt.html?highlight=itemiseditable]   PySide.QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag
[http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide]