# How to make QTreeWIdgetItems editable selectively

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

[image]

All the cells are currently editable (editable on double-click).
I only need the column 0 to be editable and all others not.
How to achieve this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        for i, item_name in enumerate(['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']):
            rootItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
            rootItem.setFlags(rootItem.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            for n in range(7):
                rootItem.setText(n, 'Root %s row %s'%(i, n)  )

            rootItem.sceneSG={}
            rootItem.sceneSG['code']='nextSceneFilename'

            for number in range(5):
                childItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(rootItem)
                childItem.setFlags(rootItem.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
                childItem.sceneSG={}     
                for m in range(7):
                    childItem.setText(m, 'Child %s row %s'%(number, m)  )

            rootItem.setData(100, 77, QtCore.Qt.UserRole )

            self.addTopLevelItem(rootItem)

        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()

tree=Tree()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801959/making-only-one-column-of-a-qtreewidgetitem-editable Second reply. I am a bit unsure of presenting the answer for Python, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you would do this with the use of a `QItemDelegate`/`QStyledItemDelegate`.  Delegates give you control over how data from the model is displayed in the view and how data from the controller/view is edited and inserted back into the model.  They allow you to do things like custom painting and custom editors.  In this case, we just check the column index and refuse to return an editor for anything but the first column.

```
class MyDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 0:
            return super(MyDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, option, index)
        return None


delegate = MyDelegate()
tree.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple I am using treeWidget's `doubleClick` signal that is processed before things get to QTreeWidgetItem's `setData` method. Since the `onDoubleClick` method gets an index we can set the item as editable or not as editable ahead of time. The working solution is posted below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        for i, item_name in enumerate(['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']):
            rootItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
            rootItem.setFlags(rootItem.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            for n in range(7):
                rootItem.setText(n, 'Root %s row %s'%(i, n)  )

            rootItem.sceneSG={}
            rootItem.sceneSG['code']='nextSceneFilename'

            for number in range(5):
                childItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(rootItem)
                childItem.setFlags(rootItem.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
                childItem.sceneSG={}     
                for m in range(7):
                    childItem.setText(m, 'Child %s row %s'%(number, m)  )

            rootItem.setData(100, 77, QtCore.Qt.UserRole )

            self.addTopLevelItem(rootItem)

        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.onDoubleClick)
        self.show()

    def onDoubleClick(self, index):
        item = self.currentItem()
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        if index.column()!=0:
            item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)

tree=Tree()
app.exec_()
```