# how to show Qtreewidget item as editable by default?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtreewidget

How to show Qtreewidget item as in editable mode? means when a data of that particular column will show it should be look like it can be edit.
Means it should be taken data as input.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item=NULL;
 item->setBackgroundColor(0,color);
    item->setIcon(0,coloricon);
    item->setText(0,QString(sample->sampleName.c_str()));
    item->setData(0,Qt::UserRole,QVariant::fromValue(samples[i]));
**//I want to show this particular column as in editable mode** 
    item->setText(1,QString(sample->getSetName().c_str()));

    item->setText(2,QString::number(sample->getNormalizationConstant(),'f',2));
```

Comment: Try to have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801959/making-only-one-column-of-a-qtreewidgetitem-editable

Comment: Try this one:
`QTreeWidgetItem* item;
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);`
Then use `QTreeWidget::editItem(... item, int column = 0)` to start edit the item

Comment: QTreeWidget::editItem(... item, int column = 0) what exactly is it? can you tell?
QTreeWidget::editItem(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column = 0); is it? @AlexanderChernin

Comment: Yes, this is it

Comment: It is not working can you give me another solution? @AlexanderChernin