# Making only one column of QTreeWidget editable // troubleshooting

Tags: c++, qt, items

Mind that this question isn't a duplicate of question [Making only one column of a QTreeWidgetItem editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801959/making-only-one-column-of-a-qtreewidgetitem-editable), as it's proposed solution doesn't work.

Hello, so I just want to make only ONE column of my treeWidget editable.

```
            propertyItems.push_back(new QTreeWidgetItem); //gets filled by the while-loop
            propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]->setText(0, prop.name); //sets the text of the item
            propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]->setText(1, prop.value);//set the text of the other item
            propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEditable);
            ui->treeWidget_3->insertTopLevelItem(ui->treeWidget_3->topLevelItemCount(), propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]); //appends the items
            counter ++;
```

and

```
void MainWindow::onTreeWidget3ItemDoubleClicked()
{
    if (ui->treeWidget_3->currentColumn() == 2) {
        ui->treeWidget_3->editItem(ui->treeWidget_3->currentItem(), ui->treeWidget_3->currentColumn());
    }
}
```

is my approach. `ontreeWidget3ItemDoubleClicked` is connected with `treeWidget::doubleClicked`, treeWidget_3 has NO `edit-triggers`

BUT: when I execute the programm, the QTreeView is just grayed out.

That said, I also tried

```
propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]->setFlags(propertyItems[propertyItem.size()].flags | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

The `treeWidget_3` isn't grayed off anymore, but it is still uneditable...

How can I fix this?

BTW: I am a newb to Qt so I might have forgotten something crucial. Sorry in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#details):

> The QTreeWidgetItem class provides an item for use with the QTreeWidget convenience class.

It means that it won't work for all use cases. The solution is to create your own model and overload the `flags(const QModelIndex& index)` method returning the [appropriate values](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) (basically `Qt:: ItemIsEnabled` for read-only columns and `Qt:: ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable` for the editable one). You can get the column from `index.column()`.

Qt provides an [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html) to start with trees and models.

Comment: In order words, the accepted solution in the other question _do_ answer this one, but you have to change from `QTreeWidget` to `QTreeView` in order to use your own model.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: THX ;) C++ is thankfully a field where you can ask questions... I had problem learning assembly because no one really wanted to help xD